# What is the proof for $(x − b)^{2} + (y − a)^{2} \geq (a − b)^{2} / 2$

Tags: inequality

I have came across this "simple fact," but I cannot figure out how to prove it. Can someone help me? Thanks!

Given $a \gt b $ and $x \geq y$, prove that

$$(x − b)^{2} + (y − a)^{2} \geq \frac{(a − b)^{2}}{2}$$

EDIT: I am sorry, I switched the inequality sign originally. Now it is correctlly writen.

Comment: Try x=y=0, a=2 and b=1?

Comment: If you take $x = y = 0$, $a, b > 0$, then the inequality isn't true.

Comment: Fix $1/2$ in the title.

Comment: @mic Title fixed

Comment: where did you come across this?

Answer (score 1):

The inequality isn't true. Take $a=2$, $y = b = 1$, then 
$$
(x − 1)^{2} + 1\leq \frac{1}{2}
$$
which is wrong for all $x$.

EDIT: this was before the sign change, i.e. $\leq$ was asked for then.

Answer (score 0):

Now with the inverted sign.

W.l.o.g., let $x = \frac{a+b}{2} + q + r$ and $y = \frac{a+b}{2} + q - r$,
where $r \geq 0$ and no restrictions on $q$. Then $x \geq y$ and otherwise any $x,y$ can be chosen by the choice of $q,r$.

Inserting this in the inequality gives
$$
\begin{align}
& (x − b)^{2} + (y − a)^{2} \\
= & \Big[ \frac{a − b}{2} + q+ r \Big]^2 + \Big[ -\frac{a − b}{2} + q - r \Big]^2 \\ 
= & 2 \Big[ \frac{a − b}{2} + r \Big]^2 + 2 q^2 \\
\geq & \frac{(a − b)^{2}}{2}
\end{align}
$$

where the last transition follows since $a >b$ and $r\geq 0$. $\quad \Box$